# Error installing Zefyr(Flutter) Method not found: 'SystemNavigator.routeInformationUpdated'

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to include the Zefyr package in my project but I get this error after importing it.

```
/C:/Users/Ahmed/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_platform_interface-1.0.9/lib/link.dart:85:21: Error: Method not found: 'SystemNavigator.routeInformationUpdated'.
    SystemNavigator.routeInformationUpdated(location: routeName);
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Ahmed/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_platform_interface-1.0.9/lib/link.dart:108:12: Error: Getter not found: 'Router'.
    return Router.of(context) != null;
```

I tried deleting the folder and pub get, but in vain, any suggestions?.

**EDIT**
flutter doctor -v result:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.22.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.572], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.0 at C:\Users\Ahmed\flutter
    • Framework revision a1097ea53f (4 months ago), 2020-07-13 17:11:02 -0400
    • Engine revision f10f172573
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-21.0.dev 06cb010247)


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.
```

flutter run --verbose result:

```
[+1665 ms] /C:/Users/Ahmed/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_platform_interface-1.0.9/lib/link.dart:85:21: Error: Method not found: 'SystemNavigator.routeInformationUpdated'.
[   +2 ms]     SystemNavigator.routeInformationUpdated(location: routeName);
[        ]                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[   +5 ms] /C:/Users/Ahmed/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_platform_interface-1.0.9/lib/link.dart:108:12: Error: Getter not found: 'Router'.
[   +6 ms]     return Router.of(context) != null;
[   +1 ms]            ^^^^^^
[+3651 ms] [+5258 ms] /C:/Users/Ahmed/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_platform_interface-1.0.9/lib/link.dart:85:21: Error: Method not found: 'SystemNavigator.routeInformationUpdated'.
[   +2 ms] [   +1 ms]     SystemNavigator.routeInformationUpdated(location: routeName);
```

Comment: What is the version of your Zefyr package?

Comment: Latest: zefyr: ^0.12.0

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the results of flutter run --verbose and flutter doctor -v?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your flutter version

run `flutter upgrade` command in terminal.